# Identifier 'n' not defined, 'object' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, templates, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code (1.17.0) generates errors in `Angular` templates when I address members from inherited types that are not on the base class and the base class is declared on the component.
In the code below, obviously `maxLength` does not exist on `QuestionBase`, but how do I go about this?

> [Angular] Identifier 'maxLength' is not defined. 'QuestionBase' does
>   not contain such a member

```js
export class QuestionBase {
  id: number;
  order: number;
}

export class TextQuestion extends QuestionBase {
  maxLength: number
}
```

On the component question is declared as QuestionBase, so that it can become any kind of question

```js
@Import question: QuestionBase
```

Now in the html template I addres the maxLength property:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="maxLength" [(ngModel)]="question.maxLength" name="maxLength" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this :

**QuestionBase.ts**

```
export class QuestionBase {
  id: number;
  order: number;
}

export class TextQuestion extends QuestionBase {
  maxLength: number
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { QuestionBase } from './';

export class Component {

    private question: QuestionBase = new QuestionBase();

    constructor() { }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="maxLength" [(ngModel)]="question.maxLength" name="maxLength" />
```

Comment: Hi Chandru, thanks. That works (my code also executes and works), but still has intellisense give the mentioned error.

Comment: you have not declared the question object based QuestionBase Schema thats was the mistake you had done.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by creating a seperate component for eacht questiontype. On each controller you can then specify the questiontype at the @Input().

```
<div [ngSwitch]="question.type">
  <app-text-question *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [question]="question"></app-text-question>
  <app-checkbox-question *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" [question]="question"></app-checkbox-question>
</div>
```

**TextQuestion**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TextQuestion } from '../../_model/text-question';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-question',
  templateUrl: './text-question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-question.component.css']
})
export class TextQuestionComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() question: TextQuestion ;

 constructor() { 
 }

 ngOnInit() {
```

And the same for the CheckboxQuestion:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CheckboxQuestion } from '../../_model/checkbox-question';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkbox-question',
  templateUrl: './checkbox-question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkbox-question.component.css']
})
export class CheckboxQuestionComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() question: CheckboxQuestion
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

}