# 'object' does not contain such a member Angular 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I am new to Angular and trying to make a small application.

I referred ['object' does not contain such a member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617738/identifier-n-not-defined-object-does-not-contain-such-a-member)
 answer but I am not getting my solution from there.

**profile.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private roter: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(
      profile => {
        this.user = profile.user;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**profile.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  <h2 class="page-header">
    {{ user.name }}
  </h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      Username: {{ user.username }}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      Email: {{ user.email }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Visual studio code is showing this
**Error:**

> [Angular] Identifier 'username' is not defined. 'Object' does not contain such a member
>
> property user of ProfileComponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change

```
user: Object;
```

by

```
user: any;
```

In your profile.component.ts this will surely work,because initially you have declared it as object so while running the or building app typescript compilation fails due to accessed as user.username.
Either you **change the type to any** or create interface or type having required properties and assign this type to user 
Ex:
profile.component.ts:

```
interface userObject {
  username:string,
  password:string
}
```

access as

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
   user : userObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have defined `user` in `ProfileComponent` class as `Object` type.wich has no `Typescript Model` defined.Therefore Typescript is unaware of the structure of the `User` Object.
 So you create a model like this.

```
interface User{
    username : String;
    password: ...
    ....
  }
```

and then use it as type like `user : User`

The problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you define an object it doesn't have firstName or lastName. So when accessing from ui it shows the error. So first initialize as given below. Then the issue will be solved.

**let user = {firstName: "", lastName:""};**

Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  let user = {firstName: "", lastName:""};
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private roter: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(
      profile => {
        this.user = profile.user;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object` refers to the inbuilt object constructor function, which obviously doesn't have the property `username`. Since you're setting the type of `user` to be `Object` and trying to access the property `username` that doesn't exist, it's showing error.

If you want to define your own types, refer [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).