# Identifier 'X' is not defined. 'Y' does not contain such a member Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying use an ngfor directive to display items from an array on the screen, and I'm getting the error "[Angular] Identifier '' is not defined. 'Band' does not contain such a member. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since everything seems to be typed correctly. Referring to ['object' does not contain such a member Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187510/object-does-not-contain-such-a-member-angular-5) wasn't helpful. Code is as follows:

Band.ts:

```
export class Band {
  constructor(
  name: string,
  pictureUrl: string,
  summary: string,
  signatureSongs: string[],
  subgenres?: string[],
  website?: string
  ) {}
```

}

band.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Band } from './band';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-band',
  templateUrl: './band.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./band.component.css']
})
export class BandComponent {

bands: Band[] = [
  new Band('Iron Maiden', 
'<long link goes here>',
`The most high-profile band of the New Wave Of British Heavy Metal, Iron 
Maiden is reknown for
            their soaring twin-guitar harmonies and energetic and elaborate live shows.`,
          ['Hallowed Be They Name', 'Phantom of the Opera', 'Wasted Years'],
        ['New Wave of British Heavy Metal', 'Classic Metal'], 'https://ironmaiden.com/'),
        new Band('Metallica', 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bc/54/5b/bc545b3f8d7344be68199bfd48e59ae6.jpg',
         `Bay Area thrash legends Metallica are one fo the most influential metal band of all time, with their
         dynamic and muscular songs.`, ['One', 'Enter Sandman', 'Master of Puppets'], ['Classic Metal', 'Thrash Metal'],
         'www.metallica.com')
];

}
```

and band.component.html:

```
<h2>Bands</h2>

<div  class="bands__container">
  <div *ngFor="let band of bands">
    <h6>{{ band.name }}</h6>
    <img src="{{ band.pictureUrl }}">
    <p>{{ band.summary }}</p>
    <p>{{ band.signatureSongs }}</p>
    <p>{{ band.subgenres }}</p>
    <p>{{ band.website }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is properly declared in the app.module file, and no other compilation errors exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor of the `Band` class takes a bunch of parameters and throws them away.  You may have intended to use [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties):

```
export class Band {
  constructor(
  public name: string,
  public pictureUrl: string,
  public summary: string,
  public signatureSongs: string[],
  public subgenres?: string[],
  public website?: string
  ) {}
}
```